# How to make Flutter ListView height same as children height(dynamic)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, listview

I want to make the ListView have a same height with its content, 
but always got **Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height** Errors 
I tried to defined a **SizedBox with a height as parent of the ListView**, but it seems weird 
All of the items was going strecth down 
How can i defined this ListView without defined a height (dynamically following the content height)? 
[The result before using listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ttznh.png) 
[After using ListView(Weird look）](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srHSt.png)

There is the code :

```
Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              ...OTHER CHILD,
              ListView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                children: [
                  HorizontalList(),
                  SizedBox(width: 10),
                  HorizontalList(),
                  SizedBox(width: 10),
                  HorizontalList(),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

There is the Child Component ：

```
Container(
      width: 260,
      height: 210,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: whiteColor,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(14)),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
            spreadRadius: 1,
            blurRadius: 5,
            offset: Offset(0, 0),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          ...OTHER CHILD,
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

Set `shrinkWrap: true` in `ListView` and wrap `ListView` with `Flexible` widget.

```
Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              ...OTHER CHILD,
              Flexible(
              child: ListView(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                children: [
                  HorizontalList(),
                  SizedBox(width: 10),
                  HorizontalList(),
                  SizedBox(width: 10),
                  HorizontalList(),
                ],
              ),
             ),
            ],
          ),
```

This way `ListView` will only take as much space as it's children need.

Comment: Got This Error : RenderIndexedSemantics object was given an infinite size during layout.
The relevant error-causing widget was
ListView

Comment: Try wrapping `ListView` inside `Flexible` widget

Comment: or try to wrap it in Expanded

Comment: YAAAAAASSS SHRINKWRAP BESTTTT

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use this

```
 crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
```

instead of this

```
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start
```

then it will work.

Comment: Got this error ： _AssertionError ('package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart': Failed assertion: line 1874 pos 16: 'constraints.hasBoundedHeight': is not true.)

Answer (score 0):

`ListView` will take all the available space.

if `scrollDirection` set to `Axis.horizontal` it will take all the available height or if it set to `verticle` then it will take all available width.
It's the default behavior.

You can use `SingleChildScrollView` with `Row`.

```
Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              ...OTHER CHILD,
              SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                child: Row(
                 children: [
                  HorizontalList(),
                  SizedBox(width: 10),
                  HorizontalList(),
                  SizedBox(width: 10),
                  HorizontalList(),
                ],
              ),
             )
            ],
          ),
```